# Please recommend a tool to draw structs / classes and pointers

Tags: software-rec, drawing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Application to help build diagrams](https://superuser.com/questions/67536/application-to-help-build-diagrams)

I know the *paper and a pen* answer, but I truly need a PC solution.

I made the example below by Word, so please recommend others more suitable and convenient.

By *suitable and convenient*, I mean I can edit more easily - for example, in Word, if I add something, I have to scale and adjust the whole. In other words, I want something a little bit like SmartArt for focusing on programming illustrations.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: the needs are different but ultimately you need a diagramming software. Will have to turn down your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal favorites:

- [**Altova UModel**](http://www.altova.com/umodel.html)  - Can be complex, but it's not necessary to use every function. (Commercial)
- [**Violet**](http://violet.sourceforge.net) - Simple, but sufficient for most technical software diagrams using UML like elements. Can run via Java Webstart so no installation required. (Free)

(*Edit: Modified Violet link to use official URL which redirects to newer site and version. Also noted Violet's support for webstart*).

Answer (score 9):

its a webapp.. but i tend to use [ASCIIflow](http://www.asciiflow.com/). dead simple and you can paste it anywhere

```
            +---------------------------+            +--------------------------+
            |Answer question            |            | ????                     |
            |---------------------------|            |--------------------------|
            | eat pizza                 |            | ????                     |
            |                           |+---------->|                          |
            |                           |            |                          |
            |                           |            |                          |
            |                           |            |                          |
            |                           |            |                          |
            |                           |            |                          |
            +---------------------------+            +---------+----------------+
                                                               |
                   +-------------------------+                 |
                   | PROFIT!                 |                 |
                   |-------------------------|                 |
                   |                         |                 |
                   |                         |-----------------+
                   |                         |
                   |                         |
                   |                         |
                   |                         |
                   +-------------------------+
```

Comment: +1 The fact it can be used anywhere, and requires no installation makes this the perfect solution

Answer (score 7):

A popular choice for this is [Dia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dia_%28software%29). Not only is it free and open-source, it's cross-platform, supports UML diagrams ([click me for some examples](http://live.gnome.org/Dia/Examples)), and has a variety of [additional libraries and shapes](http://dia-installer.de/shapes/index.html) that you can find for free.  You can also export your drawings in a variety of formats - even lossless and vector.

You can get Dia [here for Windows](http://dia-installer.de/index.html.en), or [here for Linux](http://live.gnome.org/Dia)

Comment: But not on a Mac OS... :(

Comment: @Lipis Dia is also available on OSX via various ports: http://dia-installer.de/download/macosx.html

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a UML tool. Some are incorporated into your IDEs .
Check this Wikipedia entry for a list of available [tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UML_tools).

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/products/yed/), which can also be started from a browser:

> yEd is a powerful diagram editor that can be used to quickly and effectively generate high-quality drawings of diagrams.
>
> Create your diagrams manually or import your external data for analysis and auto-magically arrange even large data sets by just pressing a button.
>
> yEd is **freely** available and runs on all major platforms: **Windows**, **Unix/Linux**, and **Mac OS**.

Comment: As it is based on Java, it can be started right from the browser...

Answer (score 0):

You might also take a look at [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com) (Windows only). There is a [free community edition](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/editions/community.jsp) available.

Answer (score 0):

I use graphviz and dot to create diagrams.
With this you can easily make diagrams from text to almost any output you like: PNG, PDF, and more (http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html).

To install: sudo apt-get install graphviz

Example hello.dot:

```
digraph G {
        fontname = "Bitstream Vera Sans"
        fontsize = 8

        node [
                fontname = "Bitstream Vera Sans"
                fontsize = 8
                shape = "record"
        ]

        edge [
                fontname = "Bitstream Vera Sans"
                fontsize = 8
        ]

        Animal [
                label = "{Animal|+ name : string\l+ age : int\l|+ die() : void\l}"
        ]

        Dog [
                label = "{Dog||+ bark() : void\l}"
        ]

        Cat [
                label = "{Cat||+ meow() : void\l}"
        ]

        edge [
                arrowhead = "empty"
        ]

        Dog -> Animal
        Cat -> Animal
}
```

$dot -T png -o Animal.png hello.dot

The result is as:

[image]

See also http://www.ffnn.nl/pages/articles/media/uml-diagrams-using-graphviz-dot.php 
and http://www.graphviz.org/